# How do i work with dynamic variables in PHP

Tags: php

I wasn't able to output the value of $id,

My first code was:

```
class add_User
{
    public function User($id) { //<-- in //
        $statement = "INSERT INTO `users` " . $this->$id. "varchar(255)"; // just nothing
        print($statement); //<-- out //
    }

    public function Moderator($id) {
        $statement = "INSERT INTO `users` " . $this->$id . "varchar(255)"; // just nothing
        print($statement);
    }
}

$check_statement = new add_User();

$check_statement->User('user1');

$check_statement->Moderator('mod1');
```

My current code works fine with just <del>$this->$id</del>, $id

Comment: You do know that your sql string is incorrect?

Comment: Yes i know, i just edited it

Comment: I just want to get the final string printed

Comment: First - `$this->id`, second `$this->id` is __not defined__.

Comment: +u_mulder, $check_statement->User('user1');  **id = user1**?

Comment: Start with PHP OOP basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues here:

- `$this->$id` would be a variable class variable. If the ID you're passing into the function was 'abc', then it would be looking for the class variable/property `$this->abc`
- `$this` implies it's a class variable. You don't have any class variables defined, so this is not what you want, either.

You're passing a variable into the function, so you want to use that. All you need to do is drop `$this`, and you'll get what you're looking for.

```
class add_User
{
    public function User($id) { //<-- in //
        $statement = "INSERT INTO `users` " . $id. "varchar(255)"; // just nothing
        print($statement); //<-- out //
    }

    public function Moderator($id) {
        $statement = "INSERT INTO `users` " . $id . "varchar(255)"; // just nothing
        print($statement);
    }
}
```

This will fix your printing. For the next step, as I mentioned in my comment, this would not be valid sql. `varchar(255)` would be for the creation of a column, not the insertion of data. So you'll still have to do some tweaking to get the query right once you get to that part.

Comment: More familiar with c, this is what i was looking for.